# How to find the best combination of numbers in order to get the maximum sum?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, google-apps-script, google-sheets, combinations

I need a solution that does the following:
From the table below, Select a number from each row and column, that are the best to sum together in order to get the maximum sum. There has to be a pick on each row and column, but picks can't be on the same row or column.
I'm open minded about the output or the method. I'm more concerned about the process here.
Thanks for any solution or advice in advance.

**TABLE**

```
14  14  12  10  9   3
0   0   0   0   0   0
14  7   16  12  10  7
8   2   3   0   0   0
10  8   9   4   3   3
12  5   5   5   0   0
```

**DESIRED RESULT:** (for example)

```
    14               
                    0
        16           
                0    
            4        
12
```

Comment: Yes, Thank You, but it's colmplicated than that. I edited the question to clarify it. (It's really hard for me to describe this problem even in my native language :) )

Comment: Post an example of a desired result then.

Comment: This is a part of a larger table in Google Spreadsheets. Any suggestion where can I ask this then?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an assignment problem. You can use the [Hungarian Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) to solve it.

Check [this GitHub](https://github.com/addaleax/munkres-js) for an implementation in Java Script.